When should reference tags be used?
Part of the TypeScript handbook's namespace documentation says (emphasis mine):

Here, we’ll split our Validation namespace across many files. Even though the files are separate, they can each contribute to the same namespace and can be consumed as if they were all defined in one place. Because there are dependencies between files, we’ll add reference tags to tell the compiler about the relationships between the files...

The beginning of the same article has a note implying that it was written long ago, so I'm wondering if modern TypeScript should follow this suggestion.
What are reference tags and when do they need to be used?

Afaik only when you use multiple <script>s with a shared global scope (as in the example), not modules.

@Bergi If the namespace were in module files instead of script files, could I use import/export to split it between multiple files?

Yes, in a module you always need to use ES6 import/export declaration. Notice that "namespace" is just a fancy word (and syntax) for an object.

Thank you! Unless there are other reasons to use reference tags, I would accept this as an answer.

I recommend running the sample code through a compiler (or putting it in the playground) and have a look at the generated output code


What are reference tags?

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-path-
They make other files and their declarations known to the compiler, like the Validation.StringValidator in the given example.

… and when do they need to be used?

In modern TypeScript that is using ES6 module syntax, basically never. Use an import declaration instead.
They're only useful when working with multiple script files (for <script type="text/javascript">) that share the global scope.

Thank you! Somehow I completely missed this article. Can you elaborate on your last sentence? I think of script files as ts files without an import/export. I think of <script>s as an HTML element that may or may not be modules, depending on its attribute. Are you using them interchangeably here?

Yes, that's what I meant, script files that will be used from a <script> tag without type="module"
